# $a+b\sqrt{-3}$ and $a-b\sqrt{-3}$ are coprime in $\mathbb{Z}+ \omega \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I want to prove that $a+b\sqrt{-3}$ and $a-b\sqrt{-3}$ are coprime in $\mathbb{Z}+ \omega \mathbb{Z}$ with $\omega$ a primitive third root of unity and $\gcd(a,b)=1$.

Approach: Assume they are not, let $s$ be an irreducible factor of $a+b\sqrt{-3}$ and $a-b\sqrt{-3}$, then $s|2b\sqrt{-3}$. Then $N(s)|6b^2$ and $N(s)|(a^2+3b^2)$....

Can someone help me how to approach a contradiction from this? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: It might help to define $N(s)$.

Comment: It's just the norm of $s$.

Comment: Of course, you need to assume $a,b$ are relatively prime, else the claim is false. Once you assume that, the rest is easy, since

$$N(s)\mid a^2+3b^2\;\;\text{and}\;\;N(s)\mid a^2-3b^2$$

Comment: @quasi Okay thanks, then you have $N(s)|a^2$ and $N(s)|3b^2$.  What's the contradiction now? Sorry, but I still don't see it.

Comment: Correction: You only get
$$N(s) \mid a^2+3b^2$$
You don't get
$$N(s) \mid a^2-3b^2$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, there's no contradiction.

Even if $a,b$ are relatively prime, the claim is false.

For example, let

$$y = 1 + \sqrt{-3}$$

$$z = 1 - \sqrt{-3}$$

Then $y,z$ are non-units, but each divides the other, hence they have a common non-unit factor.

Comment: Okay thanks, and with the extra condition that $(a+b\sqrt{-3})(a-b\sqrt{-3})=c^3$ for $c \in \mathbb{Z}$? I

Comment: That's could be a separate question (with a link back to this one),

Comment: You have any idea?

Comment: Ideas that don't fit in comments, so I recommend a new question.

Comment: Here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2276809/ab-sqrt-3-and-a-b-sqrt-3-are-coprime-in-mathbbz-omega-mathbbz

Comment: @bob: I'm writing up an answer to that question, but I'm a very slow typist, and a Mathjax novice, so it may take a while. Probably someone else will answer first, but if not, my answer will get there eventually (maybe 30 mins).

Answer (score 3):

So many things that need clarification here. What are $a$ and $b$? Are they integers, that is $a, b \in \mathbb Z$? And are you sure you're only looking at numbers of the form $a + b \sqrt{-3}$, and not also numbers of the form $a + b \omega$?

It needs to be said explicitly that $$\omega = -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{-3}}{2}.$$ With that in mind, we can rewrite $1 - \sqrt{-3}$ and $1 + \sqrt{-3}$ as $-2 \omega$ and $2 + 2 \omega$ respectively. We have changed $a$ and $b$, of course, but it should still be clear that $2 \omega$ and $-2 \omega$ have at least one prime factor in common, as do $2 - 2 \omega$ and $2 + 2 \omega$.

Also note that $N(a + b \omega) = a^2 - ab + b^2$.