# $a+b\sqrt{-3}$ and $a-b\sqrt{-3}$ are coprime in $\mathbb{Z}+ \omega \mathbb{Z}$, $(a+b\sqrt{-3})(a-b\sqrt{-3}) = c^3$

Tags: number-theory

I want to prove that $a+b\sqrt{-3}$ and $a-b\sqrt{-3}$ are coprime in $\mathbb{Z}+ \omega \mathbb{Z}$ with $\omega$ a primitive third root of unity and $\gcd(a,b)=1$, with the extra condition that $(a+b\sqrt{-3})(a-b\sqrt{-3}) = c^3$ for some $c\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Approach: Assume they are not, let $s$ be an irreducible factor of $a+b\sqrt{-3}$ and $a-b\sqrt{-3}$, then $s|2b\sqrt{-3}$. Then $N(s)|6b^2$ and $N(s)|(a^2+3b^2)$....

Can someone help me how to approach a contradiction from this? Thanks in advance!!

Edit: Without the extra condition, this question was dealt with in the thread

$\qquad$[$a+b\sqrt{-3}$ and $a-b\sqrt{-3}$ are coprime in $\mathbb{Z}+ \omega \mathbb{Z}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2276749/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $s$ is a non-unit common factor of $a + b\sqrt{-3}$ and $a - b\sqrt{-3}$.

\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&s \mid \left(a + b\sqrt{-3}\right)\;\;\text{and}\;\;s \mid \left(a - b\sqrt{-3}\right)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&s \mid (2a)\;\;\text{and}\;\;s \mid \left(2b\sqrt{-3}\right)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&N(s) \mid (4a^2)\;\;\text{and}\;\;N(s) \mid (12b^2)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&N(s) \mid 12&&\text{[since $\gcd(a,b)=1$]}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&N(s) \in \{1,2,3,4,6,12\}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&N(s) \in \{2,3,4,6,12\}&&\text{[since $s$ is a non-unit]}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&N(s)=3\;\,\text{or}\;N(s)\;\text{is even}\\[12pt]
\text{But if}\;\;&N(s) = 3\\[4pt]
\text{then}\;\;&3\mid c^3&&\text{[since $N(s) \mid c^3$]}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&27\mid c^3&&\\[4pt]
\implies\;&27 \mid (a + b\sqrt{-3})(a - b\sqrt{-3})\\[4pt]
\implies\;&27\mid (a^2 + 3b^2)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&3\mid a^2\\[4pt]
\implies\;&3\mid a\\[4pt]
\implies\;&9\mid a^2\\[4pt]
\implies\;&9\mid 3b^2\\[4pt]
\implies\;&3\mid b^2\\[4pt]
\implies\;&3\mid b\\[4pt]
&\text{contrary to}\;\gcd(a,b)=1\\[12pt]
\text{And if}\;\;&N(s)\;\text{is even}\\[4pt]
\text{then}\;\;&c^3\;\text{is even}&&\text{[since $N(s)\mid N(c^3)$]}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&8 \mid c^3\\[4pt]
\implies\;&8 \mid (a + b\sqrt{-3})(a - b\sqrt{-3})\\[4pt]
\implies\;&8 \mid (a^2 + 3b^2)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&a,b\;\text{are both even}&&\text{[since odd squares are}\\[0pt]
&&&\;\text{congruent to $1$ mod $8$]}\\[2pt]
&\text{contrary to}\;\gcd(a,b)=1\\[12pt]
\end{align*}

Either way, we have a contradiction.

It follows that $a + b\sqrt{-3}$ and $a - b\sqrt{-3}$ have no non-unit common factor.

Comment: Isn’t there a typo on the first displayed line? don’t you mean the second parenthesized quantity to be $a-b\sqrt{-3}$?

Comment: yes, thanks -- will edit

Comment: You are an hero! Many thanks!

Comment: @quasi Why is the third implication correct. If $3$ is in the prime factorization of $a$ and not in that of $b$, $N(s)$ can be equal to 3, or..?

Comment: I'm on my way out now, but yes, there's a gap. It's easily filled though. The correct version is $N(s)|12$. so either $N(s)$ is even or $N(s)=3$. If $N(s)=3$, then 

$$N(s)|c^3 \implies 3|c^3 \implies 27|c^3 \implies 27|a^2+3b^2 \implies 3|a^2 \implies 9|a^2 \implies 9|3b^2\implies 3|b$$

so $a,b$ have a common factor of $3$, contradiction. I'll edit in the fix later. Thanks for the alert.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the answer!